# View Pager is blank on Pressing back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one fragment inside that i placed a view pager consisting three fragments, when i open another fragment from any of these three fragments with the help of this code :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

it open like a charm, but when i press back button , one of the view of view pager has gone. I tried diiferent ways mentioning here in stackoverflow but there is no help.

First Fragment inside i place my viewPager code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements
        OnClickListener {

    ICallback callback;
    private LinearLayout headerContainer;
    private ImageView headerLogo;
    private TextView headerName;
    private Button menuBarButton;

    MyAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager pager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    private Button progOverview, progStr, bonusPoint;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof ICallback) {
            this.callback = (ICallback) activity;
        }
        actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = setUpView(inflater, container);

        return rootView;
    }

    private View setUpView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_about_champions_club, container, false);

        // set content of layout
        headerContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.second_top_header);
        headerContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.prog_str_blue));
        headerLogo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
        headerLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.about_champions_ticon);
        headerName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_name);
        headerName.setText(R.string.about_champ_title);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
        }
    }
    }  
}
```

and one of the fragment view which shows inside viewpager is :

```
public class ProgramOverViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ICallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof ICallback) {
            this.callback = (ICallback) activity;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_program_overview, container, false);

        TextView termsAndCond = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.terms_and_condition_button);
        termsAndCond.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and code of my adapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new ProgramOverViewFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ProgramStructureFragment();
        case 2:
            return new BonusPointFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

please tell me what i have done wrong.
**JUST a  NOTE : viewpager shows the fragments in half screen and the fragment i m opening from this is open in Full screen.**
Thank you

Comment: This problem is resolved by using add method instead of replace(), but somehow it creates another problem for me in actionBar. Perhaps this comment will help someone.