# Pager inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

As mentioned in my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549411/view-pager-is-blank-on-pressing-back-button) I had some problem with showing `Fragments` inside a `ViewPage`r after opening another `Fragment` from one of the `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager`.

I somehow managed to resolve the problem by using `add()` in the `FragmentTransaction`. Unfortunately this creates another problem:

I am using the `ActionBar` in my app. When I am selecting the same menu item twice I encounter the same problem as before, it doesn't show any `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager`.

Home Activity Code(where action bar on click events are call)

```
public class HomePageActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ICallback {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mChampionsMenuItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mChampionsMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.champions_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mChampionsMenuItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);    
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.navy_blue));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mDrawerToggle = new SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.menu_icon, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            onFragmentChange(new HomeActivityFragment(), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {    
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                onFragmentChange(new Fragment1(), false);
                break;

            case 1:
                onFragmentChange(new Fragment2(), false);
                break;

            case 2:
                onFragmentChange(new MyPointFragment3(), false);
                break;

            case 3:
                // onFragmentChange(new HomeActivityFragment(), true);
                break;

            case 4:
                onFragmentChange(new QueriesFragment(), false);
                break;

            case 5:
                onFragmentChange(new GalleryFragment(), false);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentChange(Fragment fragment, boolean flag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.commit();
    }    
}
```

This is the `Fragment` which contains the `ViewPager`:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

        ICallback callback;
        private LinearLayout headerContainer;
        private ImageView headerLogo;
        private TextView headerName;
        private Button menuBarButton;

        MyAdapter adapter;
        ViewPager pager;
        ActionBar actionBar;

        private Button progOverview, progStr, bonusPoint;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            if (activity instanceof ICallback) {
                this.callback = (ICallback) activity;
            }
            actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
            actionBar.show();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = setUpView(inflater, container);        
            return rootView;
        }

        private View setUpView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_champions_club, container, false);

            headerContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_top_header);
            headerContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.prog_str_blue));
            headerLogo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
            headerLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.about_champions_ticon);
            headerName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_name);
            headerName.setText(R.string.about_champ_title);

            adapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
            pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
            }
        }
        }  
    }
```

This is one of the `Fragments` inside the `ViewPager`:

```
public class ProgramOverViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ICallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {           
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof ICallback) {
            this.callback = (ICallback) activity;
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_program_overview, container, false);

        TextView termsAndCond = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.terms_and_condition_button);
        termsAndCond.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();    
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {    

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);    
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0: return new ProgramOverViewFragment();
            case 1: return new ProgramStructureFragment();
            case 2: return new BonusPointFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }    
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nobody is going tobe able to help you if you don't show us some relevant code or error messages. Edit them in your question please.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - Please check i updated my question with code.

Comment: Instead of calling onFragmentChange() in your onCreate() try using the .add method there only then in your onFragmentChange() method use .replace() instead of .add()

Comment: @Tinashe- yeah we can do that but in my case it will create some other problems,. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found what i did wrong in my code :

i'm using this below code for setting adapter for view Pager inside a fragment :

```
  adapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
            pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and by replacing `getFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()` we resolve this problem. As per my understanding i'm using view pager inside a fragment that's why i have to use getChildFragment manager to store transitions of my viewPager.
Might this help someone and this question is still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do exactly? Are you trying to replace a Fragment inside the ViewPager? Or are you trying to replace a Fragment inside a Fragment inside the ViewPager? Or are you trying to do something different altogether? I can only give you an accurate solution if you explain what you are trying to do in detail. Anyway here is what I am guessing might be wrong:

---

I think your problem is that you use the wrong `FragmentManager`. There are multiple different `FragmentManagers`, but essentially there are two cases:

1. You want to add/replace/remove a `Fragment` from an `Activity`
2. You want to add/replace/remove a `Fragment` from another `Fragment`

As long as I don't see your layout files I can't be sure which of those two options fits your situation.

---

## Solution if you want to replace a Fragment inside of another Fragment

If you want to perform a `FragmentTransaction` on a `Fragment` inside of another `Fragment`, then you need to use the child `FragmentManager`! You can use the child `FragmentManager` inside a `Fragment` like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

As you can see you just need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

---

As I already said, without any further information about your situation I cannot give you a more accurate answer. So please try to explain what you want to do as best as you can to me and I'm confident we can solve this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, What i'm trying to do is: I have a View pager inside a fragment, which has three views(fragment) in it. all these 3 views containing a button which will open another fragment.
** on Using replace() method :  when i'm open the fragment(by clicking on that button in any view) , fragment shows but when i click on back button, one of the view inside view Pager is got blank.
on using add() method : this above mentioned problem is resolved but inside my action bar when i click on the same tab twice(i.e. the same fragment which has view pager) my view pager views are blank.