# ViewPager blank on back from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Actually, I am using whole application in a single activity by fragments in main view container.
One fragment contains a viewPager when I clicked over a header button fragment replaced by `LoginFragment` and on Back we maintaining `backstack` so fragment containing viewPager will be on top but there we got blank view of current item in `viewPager`.

Comment: check this if your rotate the Screen does the Fragment is shown?

Comment: no its still blank...

Comment: maybe this will help you. check answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610674/pager-inside-a-fragment

Comment: I got answer by my self on debugging.
Problem was I was using fragmentPager inside fragment so there for adapter initialization we have to pass getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer by my self on debugging. Problem was I was using fragmentPager inside fragment so there for adapter initialization we have to pass getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 2):

This is my Solution and i have searched a lot of the answer so if you got a better one please share it with me..

i switched the ViewPager to the Activity

Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout ....
   xmlns.

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
 />

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 </...viewPager>
```

Activity Class

```
public MainActivity extends Activity .... {

   private boolean mShowPager;
   private FrameLayout mContainer;
   private ViewPager mPager;

   //Inflate them


  public void showViewPager() {
        mPager.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        mContainer.setVisibilty(View.Gone);
  }

  public void showContainer() {
        mContainer.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        mPager.setVisibilty(View.Gone);
  }


  public void showViewPager(boolean show) {
       mShowPager = show;
  }


  @override
  public void onBackPressed() {

        if(mShowPager) {
             showViewPager();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
```

Fragment Example

```
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

         ((MainActivity)activity).showViewPager(true);
         ((MainActivity)activity).showContainer();
```

//True means when back pressed back show ViewPager 
//Back means still show Container but do Back pressed
Info : you decide what you want to show ViewPager or the Container that contain the Fragments plus you can use the BackStack if needed.

Hope it helps its helped me.

Comment: Thanx for comment buddy but I can't change it to activity that will break whole procedure...

Comment: I got answer by my self on debugging. Problem was I was using fragmentPager inside fragment so there for adapter initialization we have to pass getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() –

Comment: Thanks for the getChildFragmentManager()! Just what I needed

Comment: Adding getChildFragmentManager() solved my problem too :) Thank you

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() solved my problem. Thanks.